# Form validate like GenericView

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

When using Generic views, you get the neat feature of django posting the error messages in the template such as "This field is required!".

From what I understand CreateView inherits a method called `form_invalid` which returns `self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))` And I'm just guessing that's what's doing the magic?

Now I'm writing a form, and was wondering if it's possible to use that feature aswell?

I have created a custom_user model, and trying to create a simple create functionality. So far I've got:

Models.py

```
class Custom_User(AbstractBaseUser):

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

forms.py

```
class create_User_Form(forms.ModelForm):

    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class' :'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Custom_User
        fields = ['email', 'password']

        widgets = {
                   'email' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' :'form-control'}),
                   'password' : forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class' :'form-control'}),
        }

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(create_User_Form, self).clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")
        confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")

        if password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "password and confirm_password does not match"
            )

        return self.cleaned_data
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
            url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),    

            url(r'^create_user/$', views.create_user, name='create_user'),  
]
```

views.py

```
def create_user(request):

    form = create_User_Form(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        print('valid')
    else:
        print('error')        

    return redirect('Eapp:index')

def index(request):

    create_user_form_ = create_User_Form()

    context = {
               'create_user_form' : create_user_form_,
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: Have a look at `CreateView` in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView). You can specify `form_class` in the View class.

Comment: @gitblame I'm not really understanding the docs, sorry about that. I've edited my post with a view function that render my index page. That's the one I'd like to show the CreateView in. Does this complicate stuff even more?

Comment: If you need some tutorial, I recommend watching [these](https://godjango.com/15-class-based-views-part-1-templateview-and-redirectview/) tutorials on CBVs from godjango.

Comment: You might need to understand the difference between class based and function based views. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/intro/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have mixed up function based views and class based view. What you have attempted is a function base view. To be complete it needs to look like this

```
def create_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        create_user_form_ = create_User_Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('valid')
            return redirect('Eapp:index')
        else:
            print('error')        

    else:
        create_user_form_ = create_User_Form()

    context = {
               'create_user_form' : create_user_form_,
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Note that this combines your index and create user methods because they contain functionality that needs to go together.

If on the other hand you want to use a [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview) your code becomes a lot shorter

```
class UserCreate(CreateView):
    model = Custom_User
    form_class = create_User_Form
```

That's it really. But you can add refinements.

As a side note. The standard way of naming classes in python is 
`CreateUserForm`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was mixing things more up. I thought View gave some sort of extra functionality. But I found out if I return the form that is invalid it'll show the errors. Had no idea that the form could be "recycled" like that.

Comment: Glad to have been of help. All the best with your project